# Dagger 2 Android application component is missing inject method

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I tried a small Android project with the newly released Dagger 2.10 with the dagger.android package.
Only the `MainApplication` class should be injected by Dagger, nothing else has any dependencies yet:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  ...
  // Dagger
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.10'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'

  // Fix for incompatible library versions when adding dagger-android and having espresso-core:2.2.2 in tests
  androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements HasDispatchingActivityInjector {

  @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      DaggerMainApplicationComponent.create();
   // DaggerMainApplicationComponent.create().inject(this); does not work - no inject(...) method!
  }

  @Override
  public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
      return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
  }
}
```

MainApplicationComponent.java

```
@Component(modules = AndroidInjectionModule.class)
public interface MainApplicationComponent {}
```

Auto-generated DaggerMainApplicationComponent.java:

```
public final class DaggerMainApplicationComponent implements MainApplicationComponent {
  private DaggerMainApplicationComponent(Builder builder) {
    assert builder != null;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static MainApplicationComponent create() {
    return new Builder().build();
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Builder() {}

    public MainApplicationComponent build() {
      return new DaggerMainApplicationComponent(this);
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to Dagger and there are lots of resources, but many are describing DI with an outdated Dagger library. What is wrong in my implementation?
I also found an auto-generated class named `MainApplication_MembersInjector`... do I have to use this myself?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component(modules = AndroidInjectionModule.class)
public interface MainApplicationComponent {
    void inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector dispatchingAndroidInjector);

}
```

Comment: Almost, but thanks - you put me on the right track. This worked: void inject(MainApplication application); instead of the Parameters you posted.

Comment: yeah, you have to use a class, inject methods won't work with an interface

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.